Why when i divide the distance of sun to earth by golden ratio, the result starts with the last 5 digits of speed of light?
When i divide 149597870700m:1.618, i get (92458)510939, the last 5 digits of speed of light, 2997(92458)?

good grief! how did you even notice that?!  By the way, its actually 92456568737.2.... using the standard AU in m and the golden ratio to 12 s.f.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a question, and it has nothing to do with Astronomy

Coincidence
Here're some reasons why:

The speed of light is 299792458 m/s. It is also 1 s/s, 5.901e+10 feet/min, or 9457698889956.7 kilometers/year.
The distance from the Sun to the Earth varies between 147.1 million km and 152.1 million km.
The golden ratio is not 1.618, it is 1.61803398874989484820... (etc.)


Using the true golden ratio φ, the Sun-Earth distance equals 92458000φ ~= 149600186.532 km twice a year, near 3 April and 5 October. The next one is ~2024-Oct-5 5:23:39 UTC https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&OBJ_DATA=NO&COMMAND=10&CENTER=%40399&EPHEM_TYPE=V&VEC_TABLE=6&START_TIME=%272024-Oct-5+5%3A23%3A35+UT%27&STOP_TIME=%272024-Oct-5+5%3A23%3A45%27&STEP_SIZE=10 :)

Because when you divide a random number by a random number there is a good chance of producing any 5-digits combination.
Same as by just inventing a number.
In fact, there is a 1:99999 chance, I've just now guessed the exact number you're just about going to think on next!
Or in other words: The 'Why' is simply chance.
And it is not unlikely at all. Ask a million people to guess your random 5 digits number, and it is near-certain, at least one will have guessed it.
What makes this "coincidence" even less impressive is, that you only get 5 digits. If there would be any causality, one would expect all of them to be correct, up to the precision of measurements.

It's a coincidence because the units are arbitrary human inventions. You can make that ratio anything by using the appropriate units.
Do this in natural units and show correlation of an interesting number of digits, and I'll be impressed.
